# Limits of sys.argv on Windows and ways to work around them?

Tags: python, windows, argv, file-processing

I'm on Python 3.10.7 and Windows 10

Long story short: Is it possible to either increase the maximum size of sys.argv or work around it?

I'm not asking if Python can ignore the limit, I'm asking if it can be worked around if not increased. Like somehow programmatically splitting arguments into multiple appropriate-length ones, make it use relative paths instead of absolutes to make it shorter therefore allow more files at least etc etc, those sort of tricks.

I want to drag-drop files on a python script and do [stuff] to the files, but if there are too many files the character size of sys.argv goes beyond the limit and nothing happens instead of running the script, annoyance ensues.

The length of sys.argv is limited by OS restraints rather than by Python, that much I know. I can't however find what the limits are on specifically Windows, nor more importantly what, if anything, can be done to work around the limit or increase the limit.

I'm converting a large amount of images to jpeg xl all over the computer so the flexibility of drag-dropping is vital, and argv seems to be the only gateway to accessing the dropped files.

I don't believe the actual script is relevant but here's a pastebin of it anyway: https://pastebin.com/thTxqeh2

The only relevant line is

```
files = sys.argv[1:]
```

And that's as plain as can be

**~Post suggestions addition~**

Doing a GUI as suggested worked great, did one using PySimpleGUIQt (needed to be Qt version of PSG, the only one with any drag-drop support currently) and tested with 1000+ files and it functioned, in the same folder that could only do about 200-250 at once using argv before hitting the limit

Comment: Python doesn't have any magic powers that let it evade OS limits.

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031210-00/?p=41553

Comment: Which is also why I precisely asked for increasing the limit, and that implicitly doesn't involve Python since it's not setting the limit. I'm not asking Python to do magic, I'm asking if the OS limit is something that can be changed or worked around to alleviate the constant annoyance. The answer seems to be no.

Comment: Or even if there's absolutely no way using argv, if there are ways not using argv at all for similar effect without said os limit. There are many many potential answers to this and your very snarky comment of "python isn't magic" is frankly both unhelpful and aggravating

Comment: If your desired workflow is "being able to drag files into my application somehow", how about writing a small GUI with a listbox to drag files into (using the regular drag & drop APIs), and it would then launch your actual tool via e.g. writing the file list to a file that the tool can read?

Comment: Ohh, I like that. Doing an actual GUI is something new to me so can't immediately try it out but yeah that feels like it might work

Comment: A common workaround is to have the program/script allow for a "response file," which is a text file that contains arguments you want to pass to the program without have to put all of them on the command line.  The program would have to recognize a reference to the response file in the regular command line, and then parse the arguments in that file.

Comment: As a workaround, you can copy the paths of all your files to the clipboard and access the clipboard inside the script using the `clipboard` module. I can't say it was fast, but this way I was able to get a list of all 765,000 files on my C drive.